# How do I indicate the end of remote candidates?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, sip, p2p

For an WebRTC application, I want to signal, that there are no more remote candidates while using Trickle ICE. The [W3C WebRTC spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/):

> This method can also be used to indicate the end of remote candidates when called with an empty string for the candidate member

and

> This can be indicated by calling addIceCandidate with a candidate value whose candidate property is set to an empty string

and

> If candidate.candidate is an empty string, process candidate as an end-of-candidates indication

and

> If this RTCIceCandidate represents an end-of-candidates indication, candidate is an empty string.

Thus, I tried different methods in Chrome 67, but non of them works:

```
pc.addIceCandidate('');
```

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The provided value is not of type '(RTCIceCandidateInit or RTCIceCandidate)'

```
pc.addIceCandidate({candidate:''});
```

> TypeError: Candidate missing values for both sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex

```
pc.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate());
```

> Failed to construct 'RTCIceCandidate': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.

```
pc.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate(''));
```

> Failed to construct 'RTCIceCandidate': parameter 1 ('candidateInitDict') is not an object.

```
pc.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate({}));
```

> DOMException: Failed to construct 'RTCIceCandidate': The 'candidate' property is not a string, or is empty.

```
pc.addIceCandidate(new IceCandidate({candidate:''}));
```

> DOMException: Failed to construct 'RTCIceCandidate': The 'candidate' property is not a string, or is empty.

Question: How do I indicate the end of remote candidates?

[EDIT]:

In 2016/2017, it was just `null`:

- https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/pull/527/
- https://webrtcstandards.info/webrtc-trickle-ice/
- http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webrtc/2017Mar/0054.html
- https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/issues/1077

> The working group decided to keep this special "all gathering is done" null candidate for backwards compatibility"

It seems, that it does not work anymore:

```
pc.addIceCandidate(null);
```

> TypeError: Candidate missing values for both sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex

```
pc.addIceCandidate({candidate: null});
```

> TypeError: Candidate missing values for both sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex

Answer (score 1):

No browser implements the spec and the spec changed opinion a couple of times. https://github.com/webrtc/adapter will ignore addIceCandidate(null) -- which is mostly required in Microsoft Edge.